# Bash Script for Publishing Git hooks

Tags: bash, github, git-bash

My project uses a single gitHub repository in which both Mac and Windows users commit their code on. 
I have set up a client side hook in order to include the JIRA Id in the commit message by modifying the commit-message hook in the hooks folder.
However,  as client side hooks cannot be published, writing a script and including it in the repo would help modify the file. Is it possible to write a common script that would work on both windows and Mac. 
The script needs to do the following.

- Rename the commit-msg.sample to commit-msg
- Replace the contents of the file to the code below

Code below

```
 commit_regex='(ISSUE-[0-9]+|merge)'
 error_msg="Aborting commit. Your commit message is missing either a JIRA      Issue ('ISSUE-1111') or 'Merge'"

if ! grep -iqE "$commit_regex" "$1"; then
echo "$error_msg" >&2
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Use a portable solution, e.g. Perl or Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a common script that would work on both windows and Mac

You simply can write a bash script: it will be interpreted by the Git bash, which does exists even on Windows.

Any executable script starting with #!/bin/bash will do.